# bind variables from storyboard and controller without using the drag and drop

Tags: swift, xcode

Is possible bind variables from storyboard with controller without using the drag and drop elements?

I don't want to use this:

[image: variable binding by dragging]

PD: i want to set custom names to the elements for easy binding

Comment: Why don't you want to use that?  Your answer could lead to a more informed answer.

Comment: No. But what's the purpose of your question?

Comment: i dont want to use the mouse for bind variables with storyboard elements, just like android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that no one sane enough would recommend you to do the other way than drag and drop. You can do this, but I actually never tried it.

Open your storyboard file in some text editor.

find tag `<viewController>` for VC you want to bind an outlet. Before end tag insert this, where:

`2Df-7S-JHW`- identifier for element(button or whatever)

`table` - name of outlet in your VC

`nZE-c6-iqY` - id for your outlet(I am not sure if you can put there anything)

```
<connections>
    <outlet property="table" destination="2Df-7S-JHW" id="nZE-c6-iqY"/>
</connections>
```

`connections` is the array of outlets, so for a new outlet just insert another one

### BINDING BUTTON ACTION

find your element tag and just before end tag insert something like this, where:

`myFunc` - name of your function

`GOf-PJ-3sa` - your VC id

`touchUpInside` - event to react to

```
<connections>
    <action selector="myFunc" destination="GOf-PJ-3sa" eventType="touchUpInside" id="ekU-Vx-7ZC"/>
</connections>
```

Comment: i dont know if it really works, ps: i want to use custom names for my elements so i can binding more easy.

Comment: `table` is your custom name. But still, I do not see any advantage of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: okey, this answer makes sense, but the id value assigned with random value scared me. probably the drag and drop binding is the only way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can give a tag for each component and retreive them with the method

viewWithTag()

Comment: don't forget to cast the view :)

Comment: i can put custom names in a tag ? or it only accept numbers?